# How to add abline to legend together with geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to add an abline to a legend in a ggplot2 plot. However, I can not get it to work. could anyone help?

Sample code:

```
## dummy script to test legends with ablines
library(ggplot2)
df1 <- iris
plot12345 <- ggplot(data = iris) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = "dummy1")) +
  geom_abline(aes(colour = "dummy2"), intercept = -3, slope = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("dummy1" = "blue", "dummy2" = "red"))
```

This only includes the first line in the legend but not the second:
[image]

Comment: Not sure how it works but put the `intercept` and `slope` inside `aes` will give what you want: `ggplot(data = iris) +
    geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = "dummy1")) +
    geom_abline(aes(slope = 1, intercept = -3, colour = "dummy2")) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("dummy1" = "blue", "dummy2" = "red"))
`

Comment: Thanks mate! Kind of weird, but it really works. Do also happen to know how to have the legend show only the line for dummy2 and only the dots for dummy1?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: ok, but if you could your comment as an answer; then I could accept it. :) Thanks again.

Comment: I think this is not a satisfactory solution and let's wait for other solutions. I'll do more research on this.

Comment: Well, thank you and I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in order to show legend for the line we can put the `intercept` and `slope` in the `aes`. (I don't know how it works but there is a similar example on page146 of Hadley's ggplot2 book);
2. in order to have the legend show only the line for dummy2 and only the dots for dummy1, we have to manipulate `guide_legend` to override the default legend aesthetics. `linetype = c(0, 1)` means blank and a solid line.

This is the final code:

```
ggplot(data = iris) +
    geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width,
                   colour = "dummy1")) +
    geom_abline(aes(colour = "dummy2", slope = 1, intercept = -3)) +
    scale_color_manual(
        values = c("dummy1" = "blue", "dummy2" = "red"),
        guide = guide_legend(
            override.aes = list(pch = c(16, NA), linetype = c(0, 1)))
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is great. I did not know about the `override.aes`command, it is great to great style legends. I have been looking for this so long.